# Execute a setup file on Windows using C

Tags: c, windows

I'm trying to create an update functionality for a multiplatform APP.
I already have the download part fully working on all platforms, but am unsure off how to proceed on Windows.

I am downloading an executable setup file to a subfolder inside my APP's instalation folder, and I was trying to launch it using _execlp, but I'm getting an INVALID ARGUMENTS error.

`execlp("./tmp/mysetup.exe","./tmp/mysetup.exe",NULL);`

I have no experience using Windows API. Am I going in the right direction, or am I cold?

Comment: do you have any checks to make sure that this is the correct path and the file exists? `"./tmp/mysetup.exe"`  .  What happens if you use a full path instead?

Comment: Have you tried it like these too: `execlp("./tmp/mysetup.exe",NULL);`, `execlp("tmp/mysetup.exe",NULL);`, etc.

Comment: @DaveS Yes, I'm positive, the Path os being passed down from the function that writes the file into the folder. Still, I'll try to force the full Path.

Comment: @FiddlingBits I haven't. Acording to the documentation on Microsoft, it should take both ARGUMENTS, as the second eill be passed as argv0 to the new process. But tomorrow I'll give it a try.

Comment: The documentation I read said `execlp` is deprecated and an alias for `_execlp`.  It looks like `_execlp` takes fewer arguments.